# node.js need to fix my function array output

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I have the following function it is working but I need the array sorting correctly
I will show you my code then I will show you my output and then the output I need

edit my full code and output

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , fs = require('fs')
  , exec = require('child_process').exec
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var async = require('async');
server.listen(process.env.PORT);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
 // console.log(async);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
//socket.emit('dinpu', { hello: 'world' });
// myModule('fam@btin.com:asdfef');
socket.on('dout', function (data) {
 //module2(data);
 //console.log(JSON.parse(data.message));
 for(i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) {
 //data.message[i] = data.message[i].replace(/"/g, ""); 

 }
 module1(data.message);
 module2(data.message);

 function module1(data) {
 console.log(data);
}


function async(arg, callback) {
console.log('do something with \''+arg+'\', return 1 sec later');
setTimeout(function() { callback(arg * 2); }, 1000);
}

function module2(data) {
function final() { console.log('Done', results); }
var items = data;
var results = [];
function series(item) {
                    if(item) {
    async( item, function(result) {
            results.push(result);
            return series(items.shift());
          });
         } else {
         return final();
    }
}
    series(items.shift());
}


});
});
```

everything works fine except for this part

```
function final() { console.log('Done', results); }
```

I get the results

```
do something with 'dfhfgh', return 1 sec later
do something with 'gfhjghj', return 1 sec later
do something with 'gfhjghj', return 1 sec later
do something with 'fghjgh', return 1 sec later
do something with 'ghjfhj', return 1 sec later
Done [ NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN ]   <    the problem
```

and if the quotations marks are not in my array then why are the showing up in the other results I don't need this

Comment: Are you saying you need to store variables in the array, not strings?

Comment: I need to remove the ' from the array

Comment: Could you please clarify your problem? You describe it as an issue of sorting, but the values don't change order between current and desired. They just have quotations stripped. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also note that `console.log()` is writing an [inspected](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) view of the values. The quotations aren't actually characters in the strings. They're just included in the log to denote that the values are strings.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to remove the ' from the array

Good news - the `'` is actually not in your array.  Your array has strings, and when you log the array, these strings are displayed surrounded by quotes.

You may safely use any of these strings; the quotes will not be there.

Comment: I sort off understand this I will post my code above and show you the error I am trying to fix

Comment: check my above code as you seen it show my results as 'string', when I need it to be string and a also get [NAN, NAN, NAN ] as my last result output